# Python sklearn.model_selection.validation_curve returns entire array of NaN values

Tags: python, scikit-learn

When I run the following code with Data matrix X of size (6859,5) and output vector Y of size (6859), it returns train_scores and valid_scores as arrays of NaN values.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import validation_curve
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold

rf_best_estimate = RandomForestRegressor()
cv = KFold(n_splits=19, random_state=42, shuffle=True)


train_scores, valid_scores = validation_curve(rf_best_estimate,X, Y, scoring='r2', 
                             cv=cv, param_name ="n_estimators",
                             param_range=np.linspace(40,100,7))
```

Similar code that I have written works fine however (in the same file, before):

```
train_scores, valid_scores = validation_curve(rf_best_estimate,X, Y, scoring='r2', 
                             cv=cv,param_name="max_depth",
                             param_range=np.linspace(5,30,16)))
```

Answer (score 1):

As `"n_estimators"` needs to be an integer, need to convert linspace to int format using `np.linspace(40,100,7)`